# Using ActiveX conntrol inside a Web Worker script

Tags: javascript, com, activex

I am converting a java desktop application, that my organization uses to export documents from our document management system to the local file system, to a browser based application.  In a attempt to move away from the desktop java application I created a HTML/JavaScript client with a J2EE server that does the heavy work.  I need to write the binary images to the file system.  I know due to enhanced security this is not going to be easy.  I wrote a custom ActiveX component to handle binary files but since I need a multithreaded approach I tried to use the web workers to handling conversion of Base64 to binary.  Any attempt to create a new ActiveX control within the context of a web worker fails.  Are COM components blocked in the context of web workers as a security measure or do I need to build or deploy them differently?

worker.js

```
var fw = new ActiveXObject("FileOps.FileWriter");
```

main page

```
var fw = new ActiveXObject("FileOps.FileWriter");
manager.postMessage({ "request": "start" }, [fw]);
```

Both methods fail

Comment: ActiveX components (which are basically COM objects) is a rather old-fashioned tech when used in a browser, as you say for security (and compatibility) issues. Microsoft is even moving its Edge browser to Chromium (none of them was supporting ActiveX anyway). So you will tie you code to IE11 (some say it's immortal https://medium.com/@burger.neal/the-end-of-life-of-internet-explorer-11-12736f9ff75f). That being said, please show us some reproducing code, not just "it fails".

Comment: COM is legacy but it's still quite useful for internal browser apps.  We plan to keep IE until MS removes support which is at least until 2025.

Comment: COM is *not* legacy at all. It's used everywhere in Windows. ActiveX components in IE is legacy and IE is legacy.

Comment: I meant to say ActiveX is legacy, though employing ActiveX in IE has been deprecated I don't know of any other technology to create an HTML application that still always you to interface with the host operating system while it's deployed on the intranet.

Comment: yep; but can you post a complete project with all needed files?